# What's the best way to auto deploy resources in SP 2010?

Tags: visual-studio, resource-files, deployment

I was wondering if there some automatic way to deploy resources (images / resource files) to IIS virutal directory from visual studio/ deployment instead of having to manually copy it to the virtual directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly what the SharePoint wsp package format is for. A quick Google found these 2 links.

- http://blog.mastykarz.nl/provisioning-appglobalresources-sharepoint-2010/
- http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-GB/sharepoint2010programming/thread/bdd711d9-cc57-495e-810a-d4fcc70d68ec-

More on [Google](http://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=visual+studio+2010+app_globalresources#sclient=psy&hl=en&safe=off&source=hp&q=sharepoint+2010+app_globalresources&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=59833b04db22fc23).

Comment: great and u can access it in code with just /AppGlobalResources/...

Comment: You may want to check out 3.2.3 and 4 in our free development guidelines as http://blog.muhimbi.com/2009/05/muhimbis-sharepoint-development.html